# Using Target.Column every nth column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 6 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub••••ˇˇˇˇ
```

I am trying to use Target.Column to start at the 6th column and use the same code for every 3 columns after as well so basically 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, etc.

```
If Target.Column = 6 Then
```

How would I go about implementing that here

Comment: You could probably use `Mod`.

Comment: ^^^ this ^^^ : `n` is divisible by `3` when `n Mod 3 = 0`, see [Mod Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function and check the correct column number via `If correctCol(target.Column) Then`:

```
Function correctCol(ByVal col As Long, Optional floor As Long = 6) As Boolean
correctCol = (col Mod 3 = 0) * (col >= floor)
End Function
```